# Website whitelisting on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, whitelist

I'm in the process of setting up a Linux (Ubuntu 18-04) machine for my son, and while it will be connected to the network, I obviously don't want him with unbridled access to the entire Internet.

How would I go about establishing a list of whitelisted websites, thereby default blacklisting all other websites, and still allow other software (such as apt and software center(?) etc.) to still allow access to their respected servers? Effectively restrict the whitelist to internet browsers only.

Comment: Depends how old and how computer-savvy he is. He could boot a live USB to circumvent whatever you put on the disk. As a parent, I never put any filters on the computer, but 1)  I made the two kids aware that I could retrieve logs, 2) put the computer in a common room, so that 3) the two kids monitored each other, in the (infrequent) case there was no parent around.

Comment: @xenoid not if the boot manager is password-protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it is changing the DNS server to the servers of OpenDNS.

They have a free service called "[Family Shield](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/)" that bans a lot of adult domains.

[Here](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu) is the link to the configuration instructions.